# What does ${N\choose\mu}$ mean where $\mu = (\mu_1, ... , \mu_n)$ be the vector of nonnegative integers for which $\sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i = N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, notation, combinations

When I've read [Cohn et al. paper 2005](http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~umans/papers/CKSU05.pdf), I've met a strange object in lemma 1.1 that looks like number of combinations: ${N\choose\mu}$ where $\mu = (\mu_1, ... , \mu_n)$ be the vector of nonnegative integers for which $\sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i = N$. After "reverse engineering" of lemma's proof I've got that ${N\choose\mu}=\prod_i \left({\mu_i \over N}\right)^{-\mu_i}$, but what does it mean?

Comment: [wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That notation usually denotes a [multinomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients):
$$\binom{N}{\mu}=\binom{N}{\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n}=\frac{N!}{\mu_1!\cdots\mu_n!}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** *This is written as an answer as I was unable to get the $\LaTeX$ code working as a comment, but really it should be a comment.*

Just to add to @ZevChonoles comment, it is a generalistion of the binomial coefficient. Indeed 
\begin{align*}\left(\begin{array}{cc}N\\p\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}N\\p,N-p\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}N\\N-p\end{array}\right).\end{align*}